# UrlRewriting does not work on server, but on localhost it works fine on asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, url-rewriting, seo, webforms-routing

```
 <urlrewritingnet rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true" contextItemsPrefix="QueryString" defaultPage="default.aspx" defaultProvider="RegEx" xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
    <rewrites>
      <add name="book" virtualUrl="^~/book/(.*?)/([0-9]+)$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/book.aspx?title=$1&amp;id=$2" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="page" virtualUrl="^~/page/(.*?)/([0-9]+)$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/page/default.aspx?title=$1&amp;id=$2" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="register" virtualUrl="^~/register/(.*?)$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/register.aspx?title=$1" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="login" virtualUrl="^~/login$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/login.aspx" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="download" virtualUrl="^~/download/(.*?)$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/download.aspx?title=$1" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="forgotpass" virtualUrl="^~/passwordrecovery$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/forgotPassword.aspx" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="newsarchive" virtualUrl="^~/news-archive$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/newsarchive.aspx" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="newsarchivekeywords" virtualUrl="^~/news-archive/(.*?)$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/newsarchive.aspx?title=$1" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="news" virtualUrl="^~/news/(.*?)/([0-9]+)$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/news.aspx?title=$1&amp;id=$2" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="articlearchive" virtualUrl="^~/article-archive$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/articlearchive.aspx" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="articlearchivekeywords" virtualUrl="^~/article-archive/(.*?)$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/articlearchive.aspx?title=$1" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="article" virtualUrl="^~/article/(.*?)/([0-9]+)$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/article.aspx?title=$1&amp;id=$2" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
      <add name="search" virtualUrl="^~/search/(.*?)$" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/search.aspx?s=$1" ignoreCase="true" processing="stop" />
    </rewrites>
  </urlrewritingnet>
```

here is my web.config codes. evry thing is ok in localhost(iis) but when i published to server. i just got this

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try to add this to your we.config and the problem has been solved

```
      <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriteModule"
           type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```